# rails path for json call on folder based apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if anyone has tried this. A normal web application can either be deployed

1. in a domain style: ex: http://www.webapp.com/
2. Subdomain style: ex: http://webapp.domain.com/
3. In a virtual directory style: ex: http://www.domain.com/webapp

My problem relies on option 3.

A typical json/ajax call goes like this:

```
$.getJSON("<%= somecontroller_somemethod_path%>.json", params, function(result) {
//code here
});
```

This code runs fine on option 1 and 2 but on option 3 it breaks. The call is not sent to http://www.domain.com/webapp/somecontroller/somemethod.json, it leaves the webapp out.

How can I fix this? and is it possible to test/debug this on my localhost, serving the app in `localhost:3000/webapp` instead of `localhost:3000` like normally I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is explained in the [guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root). You have to add a line to your `config/application.rb` or to the environment configuration:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/webapp"
```

Comment: Nice, I had the problem with "how can I search this?" and never ended up there with the keywords I used. This is a good start